# What is the likelihood formulation that describes observations with correlated error

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, likelihood, error

Consider we observe a sample $y_i$ that is distributed according to the Normal distribution $f_X$ with unknown mean value $μ$ and known variance $σ^2$. The likelihood that describes this sample is thus:

$L_i(μ)=f_X(y_i|μ)$

In the case this sample is subject to an additive error $ε_i$, we write $y_i=X+ε_i$ or $ε_i=y_i-X$, where $X$ is the true value. Then, the probability of observing a sample $y_i$ given that the true value is $X=x$, is equal to $ε_i$ taking the value $y_i-x$, namely:

$f(y_i|x)=f_ε(y_i-x)$

Assuming an error normally distributed, $f_ε$ is the PDF of Normal distribution with zero mean and known standard deviation $σ_ε$.

The resulted likelihood, applying the multiplication and consistency rules, describing this sample is then:

$L_i(μ)=$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y_i|x)f_X(x|μ)dx= $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_ε(x-y_i)f_X(x|μ)dx$

For a set of statistically independent samples $Y={(y_1,y_2,...,y_n})$ the joint likelihood becomes:

$L(μ)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n L_i(μ)$

The question is: How to derive the likelihood function for a set of samples $Y={(y_1,y_2,...,y_n})$ with correlated error described by their covariance matrix $Σ_ε$?